# Help with question from Sipser chapter 1

Tags: finite-automata

Is this language regular?

$0^k10^k \ with \ k\geq1$

It needs to count the starting and ending zeros which is impossible with finite states.

Update:
This is the whole problem from the book:

Let $\sum = \{0,1\}$.
Let $A =\{0^ku0^k  \ | \ k \ge 1 \ and \ u \in \sum^*$}.
Show that $A$ is regular.

My reasoning is that $u$ can be $\{0,00,000,...,01,011,...,1,11,111,11111...etc\}$

So, the language $0^k10^k \ with \ k\geq1$ should be regular.

I don´t want a formal proof of the problem, but to check if my reasoning is correct.
Thanks.

Comment: Your reasoning is all correct. Where you want help? Do you want formal proof using Pumping Lemma?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: It appears that the language $A$ can be described by the regular expression $0 \{0,1\}^* 0$ and hence is regular.  However, $\{0^k 1 0^k: k \ge 1\}$ might require storing the $0$'s and so might not be possible with a finite automata.  It would be possible with a push down automata.

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally understood the concept.

This:

$A =\{0^ku0^k  \ | \ k \ge 1 \ and \ u \in \sum^*$}.

Means that A has strings that starts and ends with the same number of zeros.

For example, the string:

$0000000100$

Is recognized by A because:

$00|000001|00$

In the middle we can put any number of zeros and shrink the zeros at the edges.

$0^k10^k$ is another language that contains strings with equal number of zeros at the beginning and end separated by a 1. In this case, string from this language are accepted by the the first one but that doesn't means that the second language could be regular.

Comment: In fact, $A$ is the set of all strings that starts and ends with one or more zeros.

Comment: A is just the language of strings that begin and end with a single 0 since u can be any string.

Comment: So it's easy to build a DFA that recognizes A.